# Can ampersand-model contain an ampersand-collection?

Tags: javascript, ampersand.js

Clearly an `ampersand-model` can exist in a `ampersand-collection`, and have a reference to the parent's collection. But, can it, itself, have a `ampersand-collection`?

Pseudo code..?

```
var Collection = require('App/Collection/Foo');
var BaseModel.extend({
  props: {
    foo: Collection
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, with `collections` field you can declare collections contained in your model:

```
var Collection = require('App/Collection/Foo');
var MyModel = BaseModel.extend({
  collections: {
    foo: Collection
  }
});
```

See http://ampersandjs.com/learn/state#child-models-and-collections